# Почему не работает if в Python?

Tags: python, if

Всем привет, пишу код с элементарным условным оператором if. Казалось бы, все просто, но почему-то когда я ввожу 1, меня сразу кидает на else. IDLE ошибок не показывает.

```
menu = int(input("Hello, my Sir! Please, choose needed section: \n1) Piggy Bank\n2) Wallet\n3) Credit card\n4) Dollar deposit\n"))
if menu == "1":
    pig = int(input("What would you like to do?: \n1)View the available funds\n2) Add money\n3) Distract money\n"))
elif menu == "2":
    print ("Two")
else:
    print ("WHAT?")
```

Comment: Вы конвертируете `input` в `int`, а потом сравниваете его с строкой("1")

Comment: кстати int там зря стоит - если ввести букву то будет ошибка.а если убрать инт, то напишет "WHAT?"

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Ты конвертируешь ввод в число, но сравниваешь со строкой.

```
menu = int(input("Hello, my Sir! Please, choose needed section: \n1) Piggy Bank\n2) Wallet\n3) Credit card\n4) Dollar deposit\n"))

if menu == 1:
    pig = int(input("What would you like to do?: \n1)View the available funds\n2) Add money\n3) Distract money\n"))

elif menu == 2:
    print ("Two")

else:
    print ("WHAT?")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, невнимательность меня погубит :)